# React-Native - Issue with button showing

Tags: react-native, flexbox, reactjs

I am **very** new to `react-native` and so I am just trying to stumble through user guides and playing around trying to figure things out.

I am having trouble getting a button to show up that I thought I have done correctly. Looking for some suggestions as to why its not appearing.

**Logout Button Component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Icon } from 'native-base';

// Create our logout button
const LogoutButton = ({ children, buttonStyle, onPress, icon, text }) => {

  return (
    <Button onPress={onPress} style={buttonStyle}>
      <Icon name={icon} />
      {text}
    </Button>
  );

};

export { LogoutButton };
```

**User Panel:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Header, Title, Content, Footer, FooterTab, Button, Icon, Text } from 'native-base';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { LogoutButton } from './common';


export default class UserPanel extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <Container>
            <Header>
            <Button transparent>
                <Icon name='ios-menu' />
            </Button>
                <Title>Dashboard</Title>
                <LogoutButton text="Logout" icon="ios-home" style={styles.logout} onPress={() => firebase.auth().signOut()} />
            </Header>
        </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

**Button should be to the right of "Dashboard".**

I am guessing it has something to do with styling?

[image]

Comment: Try setting the `backgroundColor` of some of those components, it usually helps to visualiza and sometimes, they magically appear.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest NativeBase [Header.js](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/master/Components/Widgets/Header.js) Line 77 onwards, type checking will be performed on its children and render only the following components: `<Button>`, `<Title>`, `<Subtitle>`, `<InputGroup>`.

Even `<LogoutButton>` is returning `<Button>` component, it will still be ignored due to its type.